# What does a "for i, v" loop do?

Tags: lua, roblox

I understand, "for i, v" loops for tables, i is the index, and v is the value, but what does this script do? I do not think this has anything to do with tables, but the only type of for table loops I know in ROBLOX script is the first one I mentioned; "for i, v" loops, which loop through tables.

```
randomVariable = 1
for i = 1, randomVariable do
(random script)
end
```

Comment: loops are made to do things *more than once*.  if you start at one and end at one, then you're programming in extra steps that aren't needed.  your randomVariable would have to be larger than one, or this wouldn't be a loop.

Answer (score 2):

This is a numeric loop statement.

```lua
for controlValue = startValue, endValue, stepValue do
    -- for body
end
```

It goes from `startValue` until it reaches `endValue`, after running `body` code, `controlValue` is increased by `stepValue`. If `controlValue` is higher or equals to `endValue` the loop stops. If `stepValue` is not provided, it equals to `1`.

It's equivalent to this code:

```lua
local controlValue = startValue
if not stepValue then stepValue = 1 end -- if no stepValue it equals to 1

while controlValue < endValue do
    -- for body
    controlValue = controlValue + stepValue
end
```

Comment: I know that I shouldn't comment thanks, but I don't care; thank you. I have heard of these types of loops but I did not understand the loop in this context, again thanks.

Comment: @234fsdafwef They are used to repeat code multiple times. It can be from 1 to 10. or From 100 to -1000. Depends on your needs.

Comment: @234fsdafwef If you find an answer helpful, be sure to give it an upvote. You can also mark one answer for each question as "accepted". More on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Also, as you mentioned, "thank you" comments are discouraged.

Answer (score -2):

There are a few different ways to loop in Lua.

`while variable < number do`

`repeat stuff until variable == number`

`for key, value in pairs do`

`for index, value in ipairs do`

```
for i = 1, number do
```

---

`i = 1` is the initial condition.

It usually begins at one, then loops through items in a table.

So you can think of it as an index in that regard.
where the `randomVariable` you mentioned would be `#tab`

---

however, you could set that initial condition to be larger, then count down.

```lua
for i = #tab, 1, -1 do
```

the third, optional argument is called "step size"
and it's the amount that initial condition is changed, after completing each loop.  it defaults to 1, so it's not needed, most of the time.

so to step through all the even numbers in a table it would be

```lua
for i = 2, #tab, 2 do
```

Further reading: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/lua/lua_loops.htm

Comment: i, the initial condition, usually begins at one.  this isn't hard to follow.  it's literally contained within a border, how could it be anything else?